# Sublime Text 3 Syntax Coloration Issues PHP/HTML

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

This is my first post on stackoverflow, and I'm glad to be here.

So I have a syntax coloration issue with Sublime Text 3 in a single file .ctp (Cakephp Template). I use Php and Html in this same file. The coloration doesn't seems to work in the wrapped language.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkav3.png)

What could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install the [CakePHP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CakePHP%20(Native)) package, since it adds syntax highlighting for those template files

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking with "Syntax > html" and "Syntax > php" I get the correct coloration for this case. But in Php files, when you're making a helper for exemple, it's still broken for somes parts.